Use pandas to turn cell value to column header and show count of that value as new value
I have a dataframe df that returns this table



City
State
Indicent




New York
New York
foo


New York
New York
bar


Los Angeles
California
foo


Los Angeles
California
bar


Miami
Florida
foo


Miami
Florida
bar


Miami
Florida
bar



I have tried getting my head around  .groupby functions but I can't seem to get it to return the table I want, which is:



City
State
Foo incident count
Bar incident count




New York
New York
1
1


Los Angeles
California
1
1


Miami
Florida
1
2



I have tried df.groupby(by='City').value_counts() but that obviously didn't work. I've read some solutions to similar problems but none that I've seen applicable to this one specifically. Any help is appreciated.

You want a pivot_table/crosstab
